# Load Runner => Action.c(1279): Error -26630: HTTP Status-Code=401 (Unauthorized) IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7, load-testing, loadrunner

I'm receiving this error from load runner

> Action.c(1279): Error -26630: HTTP Status-Code=401 (Unauthorized) for
> xxxxxxxx

Even when I used browser in same time of using the tool I get 401 error.

- ASP.NET Core application
- IIS

Comment: What did you do and how you set IIS or application? If others cannot reproduce your problem, it is difficult to provide useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> even I used browser in same time of using the tool I get 401 error

What's your theory of what is happening and what testing have you done to validate your theory?